# why stat() does not work from windows service

Tags: windows

stat() of the file located in the shared folder in a windows service program returned error -1 and errno turned out to be 2 (ENOENT).

system where the shared folder exists and system where the service is run are in the same domain. 
Logged in to service using a valid username/paswd for an account in that domain.

when the same program is run as a EXE stat() returns successfully (0).

Why is the difference in behavior? How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Services run from their own context. That context does *not* include access to any shares that are owned by a particular user. It's not a permission issue, it's a namespace issue.

There are a lot of possible workarounds. One is to [run the service under the Network Service account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249928/executable-started-by-a-windows-service-using-the-local-system-account-cannot-ac). Another is to have the service replicate the mount itself with an [appropriate system call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385413%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The workaround that I prefer is to use a helper process that runs in the user's application context. The helper process can do all file I/O on behalf of the service.

Comment: That context does not include access to any shares that are owned by a particular user.                                               >>shouldn't it work if I log-on the service using a valid username/paswd of a valid account in that domain.

Comment: No. It's not a permissions issue, it's a namespace issue. Normally, you wouldn't want the user to be messing with the service's mounts.

Comment: I Log-on to the service as a NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE and restarted the service. Then granted file in network share permission as in here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647402.aspx#paght000015_fileaccess . both are in same domain. Still I am unable to access the file. Did I miss anything?

Comment: found solution to my problem, it was because I was using mapped shared drive. Found solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098486/cannot-access-files-on-drive-mapped-network-share-from-a-windows-service